# Как сделать связь выпадающих списков страна, город?

Tags: c#, html5

Как сделать связь выпадающих списков страна, город? Город сначала не показывается и заполняется автоматически при выборе страны. В MS Express для Web 2015 в форму закинул 2 элемента DropDownList. Связал их с СУБД SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, но ни как не получается сделать так, чтобы при выборе страны в первом выпадающем меню изменялся город во втором выпадающем меню. Скрины: [first](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3KIIbzlo9PlRExydWV6eUVQMUU), [second](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3KIIbzlo9PlS1l2ZnIwamZjTU0).
Код:

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>    
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="City">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Country], [City] FROM [Tab_1]">

Здесь код не корректно отображается, [ссылка на код](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17HhC-7rNGJzBmbC4tZIU8vM5pKDWycRyKwra9TxTCR8).
Пожалуйста подскажите как можно выполнить данную задачу, перебрал множество статей, но примеры были либо не рабочие, либо на PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Если вкратце, то тебе надо изменять SelectCommand у второго меню при срабатывании события SelectedIndexChanged на первом меню.

Пример решения: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897672/how-to-create-relationship-between-two-combo-box-in-c-sharp-winform-application

Comment: Спасибо, разбираюсь.